# can not push my repo's local version to github

Tags: git, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

[image]
when I am pushing my code to my repository created in github.com using git,an error occured liked above but I remember clearly I can normaly push using git yesterday.It is not the first time this error occured but it just like a ghost,sometimes it happens sometimes it hides,but I try to push a whole night today,failed at last.
The message is behind when I typed `ssh -T git@github.com` :
[image]
The shell I used is wsl2 Ubuntu-20.04.
I used the command : `ssh -t rsa -C "<user.email>"` to regenerate my ssh key one to two times but it still don't work.
And I use the comman : `git config --local -e` to change the url of remote from git@github.com/username/repo.git to https://github.com/username/repo.git,but still failed.

I have tred many ways I can find in google,expecting successfully push my code to github.com

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`? Did you upload your public SSH key to GitHub?

Comment: The output of git remote -v is just as normal,my repo's name.yeap I`vd already upload my ssh key to github.I retry today and it somehow worked........

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that GitHub is telling your computer to shut up and go away *during the key exchange identification phase*, which happens long before your own personal keys go out.

The exact reason for this is not determinable from the above: there are far too many possible reasons.  See, for instance, [What causes SSH error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host?](https://serverfault.com/q/1015547/549786)  Consider doing a Google search for `kex_exchange_identification`.  (Watch out for typos; I had to type this in manually here since you used a screenshot instead of cutting and pasting the actual error text.  See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))