# git pull encounters kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys, openssh

When I used `git pull` to pull code from GitHub, I encounted the following error:

```bash
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 20.205.243.166 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm sure this ssh key worked fine until yesterday, But I don't know why this error occurs. My laptop is Macbook Air 13, Monterey 12.4. Can anyone help me? Thank a lot.

I try `ssh -vT git@github.com` to debug, but it seems that there is no bug. I don't know how to handle, can anyone help me? Thank a lot. The following is the msg output by `ssh -vT git@github.com` (username is replaced by ${username})

```bash
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/${username}/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/${username}/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/${username}/.ssh/id_github_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/${username}/.ssh/id_github_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 20.205.243.166 port 22
```

Comment: Do you see `Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` with your `ssh -vT git@github.com`?

Comment: No, the info I see is `kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host. Connection closed by 20.205.243.166 port 22` if I use `ssh -T git@github.com`

Comment: I try to add a new ssh key to GitHub and now it works find. but I want to figure out why this problem happened.

Comment: So... it was not related to your key, then, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440661/6309)

Answer (score 3):

You can perform the following two steps to solve

1. Delete the local `~/.ssh` directory, regenerate the keygen, and paste it into GitHub:

```bash
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "youremail@example.com"
```

Open `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (win `C:\Users\name\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`) and copy the contents

Go to [GitHub SSH and GPG keys](https://github.com/settings/keys) and create a new `SSH keys` paste the content and save it

Test：

```bash
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Displaying `Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` is fine

If there is still `Connection closed by 20.205.243.166 port 22`, then execute Step 2

2. Add configuration

Create/Modify `~/.ssh/config` file, add the following code:

```
Host github.com
    HostName ssh.github.com
    User git
    Port 443
```

If it times out, just try again using the VPN global

Answer (score 1):

If you use VPN, then the problem is most likely that you do not have a terminal proxy enabled.

When I turned on the **terminal proxy**, the problem was successfully solved.
I use the macOS system. In macOS, the success of the browser proxy does not mean the success of the terminal proxy.
For example, my proxy port is 7890, I run the following command:

```
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890 http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890 all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not connected to a VPN, or if you are, make sure it is not in enhance mode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I add `ProxyCommand nc -v -x 127.0.0.1:7890 %h %p` to `~/.ssh/config`， then it works...

config content

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User yourUsername
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
    ProxyCommand nc -v -x 127.0.0.1:7890 %h %p
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the Hostname for Git on my ~/.ssh/config, which fixed my issue. I was on VPN when I came across the same issue as yours.

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using network proxy like vpn, try to enable it and try again, it works for me. In addition, if you havn't set proxy rules for port 22 you may need to set it up.